# Importing x,y data table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to import my x,y table using ArcGIS, but when I attempt to import the data the x,y fields refuse to appear.

Comment: What format is the table in? Is it Excel, CSV or other sort of table. How are you importing it? What are you trying to make it into? Do you get any error messages or do you just get an empty table? Can you give an example of the contents of the table, a screenshot of the table as it exists now would probably be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. In it you'll see that questions are expected to `Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do`. Please [Edit] the question to address Michael's clarification requests.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely because the the fields are not in the correct format. I believe they need to be numeric, not text. Check what type the x,y data is in and change them to numbers.

Comment: Or the x and y field names use invalid characters like spaces or start with numbers.